# Is this transcription correct?

Tags: spoken-language, transcription

I saw a video clip with English subtitles and tried to transcribe the Japanese audio. Can anyone tell me if I did it correctly?

**English subtitles:**

> monster get out ; you've got no right to drink that water; get outta here;

**Attempted transcription of Japanese audio:**

> oni wa soto ; oni wa mizu ***natte mo tsukanai*** de; achi ike ;

In particular, I have problems with the bold italicized words.

The link to the video clip: [setsubun festival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_x43sN80o0)

Comment: Not sure what you're going for with the bold there.  I'd probably go with something to the effect of お前は水を飲む権利がない ("omae wa mizu wo nomu kenri ga nai") if I were translating it myself.  And probably 出て行け for the other bits.

Comment: @Kaji I think you misunderstood what the OP was asking. I've tried to reword the question using my interpretation... I hope I'm correct.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie *Transliteration* is from one system of writing to another (*liter* there is cognate with *letter*). *Transcription* is the term for writing down what you hear.  So for example, writing 行こう as `ikou` is transliteration because it's representing kana rather than pronunciation.  But you can't transliterate audio.

Comment: @snailboat Sure, but isn't transcribing audio into a different writing system transliteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have guessed, you got the bold part wrong. This is what it actually is:

> 鬼は外！鬼は水**なんて飲む資格ないんだよ**！あっち行け！
>   oni ha soto! oni ha mizu **nante nomu shikaku nain'dayo**! acchi ike!

Comment: oh thank you so much.
instead of nomu shikaku, i was vainly looking up meanings for 'no mushika na inda....' i didn't get anywhere. so i assumed what i wrote in my question. 

thank you Darius. I appreciate it